# Synchronization problem with fetching data from json-server and show in UI using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, axios

I can get data from json-server and show in UI but there is a problem that always confusing my mind. Fetching data is an asynchronus process, so when i try to fetch data and set the state, actually this operation needs time to set the state. So, sometimes when i try to reach data and showing in UI, the data comes undefined cause of asynchronus process. I overcome this situation with using ternary operator like if the data not undefined then show in or dont show until the rerendering. But when i dont want to use ternary, it cause an error. What is the reason of this and why it happening sometimes?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import BurgerImage from '../assets/burger.jpg';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Data() {

  const [data, setData] = useState();


  const getData = async () => {

    let response = await axios('http://localhost:3000/burger', {});
    setData(response.data);

  }

  useEffect( () => {

    getData()

  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, index) => 
      <div key={index}>
        <h3>{item.name}</h3>
        <img src={BurgerImage} alt="test" />
        <p>{item.content}</p>
        <p>{item.price}</p>
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I encounter the error shown below:

[image]

Also i figure it out that, when i give the empty array as an initialValue to data state,
`const [data, setData] = useState([]);`  and when set the data with `setData([...data, ...response.data])`,  i don't need ternary operator anymore to show data in UI. What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason of this?

Since you have not set a *default* value for `data`, it will be initially set to `undefined`. The `map` function can be called only on *arrays*, that's why your app crashes.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]); // use the default value to avoid the error
```

Either you can use *optional chaining* (`?`), so the `map` function will be called only if `data` exists.

```
{data?.map((...)}
 // ^^^
```

Comment: Oww, you are right, map function doesn't throw an error when the array is empty. So we can't see anything on the screen until re-rendering. i just missed it. Thanks for your answer.